# all arrays are not showing with angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my controller that will fetch all notes for my main page. When I `console.log($scope.allNotes)` all my arrays are logged but when I render with my HTML only 1 array shows up

```
exports.allNotesController = function ($scope, $http, $notes) {
      $notes.fetchNotes().then(function (result) {
        var data = result.data
        data.filter(function (notes) {
          $scope.allnotes = notes.notes
          console.log($scope.allnotes)
        })
      })
    }
```

my HTML:

```
<section class="row all-notes">
  <h1>All Notes</h1>
  <div class="allNotes">
    <ul ng-repeat="notes in allnotes">
      <li>{{ notes }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#/login">Login</a>
```

[image: https://gyazo.com/634e649882017de0a887077e1d954296]

Comment: Can you post how your json looks like? jsfiddler link will help.

Comment: You are overwriting `$scope.allnotes`, so only the last array will win. Do not overwrite it.

Comment: Also, what's up with that `data.filter`?

Comment: I was hoping the image will help. I'm getting this array from my factory, and my factory gets it from my db. I don't think jsfiddler will help.

@SergioTulentsev Im only logging the `$scope.allnotes` to see what it has, and it has the data that I need but when the `HTML` renders it only shows up one array. 
I use `data.filter` because my array is an embedded element in a document from my db.

Comment: You don't need `data.filter` here to access embedded elements. And the root of your problem is this statement: `$scope.allnotes = notes.notes`

Comment: You need `map`, not `filter`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. When I removed `data.filter` and just served `result.data` to my HTML,  I get both arrays but it comes out like this `["test1"] ["test2"]`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a very hacky way.

Heres my new controller

```
exports.allNotesController = function ($scope, $http, $notes) {
  $notes.fetchNotes().then(function (result) {
    $scope.allnotes = result.data
  })
}
```

my HTML, this is where the magic happens. lol

```
 <ul ng-repeat="notes in allnotes track by $index">
   <li>{{ notes.notes.toString() }}</li> // i had no idea I can use toString() here
 </ul>
```